# Is it OK to ask about travel search services?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm considering asking about different kinds of travel search services (Kayak, et al), specifically regarding if anybody knows of a service that has specific kinds of search (flights by price alone, not filtered by date or location but perhaps sortable by date or location... specifically looking for "cheap getaways" and not terribly concerned with destination).

However, the FAQ is a bit unclear to me in this regard.  On the one hand, it's a question about "modes of traveling" (finding flights) and "finances" (searching by price):

> If you have a question about ...
>
> - modes of travelling: international, domestic, and public transport
> - finances: budgets, costs, foreign exchange

But on the other hand, it's a question about "cheapest [things]" and "shopping suggestions."

> and it's not about …
>
> - cheapest [things, places] in [country, town, ...]
> - shopping suggestions

Would such a question be entirely unwelcome on Travel.SE?

Reading through some other Meta questions, to clarify this is less a question of "What's the cheapest way to get from X to Y" and more a question of "How can I find cheap flights out of X (where X is unspecified)?"

Comment: Yes, such a question will be welcome. In fact, [we already have it][1]!


  [1]: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, such a question will be welcome. In fact, [we already have it](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/730/how-can-i-do-a-broad-search-for-flights)!

There are other, similar questions so unless it's something significantly different it might be merged into one of the existing questions.

Comment: Ah, my search didn't turn that up, thanks!  It is quite similar to my question indeed :)